# Why isn't my UITableViewController being populated here?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, asihttprequest

Just trying to understand my table isn't being populated when my view controller appears here. I'm using AIHTTPRequest to communicated with a REST API. The call returns an array of associative arrays (which I'm assuming I'll have to cast to an NSArray of NSDictionaries).

In the header of my TableViewController:

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSArray *homepageItems;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray * homepageItems;
```

In the implementation:

```
@synthesize homepageItems;
....
- (void)viewDidLoad {

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URL_TO_MY_API];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

When the data is returned:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    id response = [responseString objectFromJSONString];
    homepageItems = (NSArray *)response;
}
```

And in the Table View method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSDictionary *dataItem = [homepageItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [dataItem objectForKey:@"message"];

    return cell;
}
```

When the view loads nothing is in the table. I suspect this is happening because when the table view method is fired homepageItems hasn't been populated by the asynchronous method. How can I achieve the data being loaded into the table view?

Thanks,

**EDIT:** In my requestFinished method, I've examined the homepageItems object by doing the following:

```
for(NSDictionary *dictionary in homepageMMDs) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"message"]);
}
```

And the proper messages from my API service are being logged.

Comment: Are you sure that the data you download is directly an array, and not an array in a dictionary or something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not retaining the downloaded data:

Instead of:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data.
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    id response = [responseString objectFromJSONString];
    homepageItems = (NSArray *)response;
}
```

You need to do: (crucially using `self` in front of `homepageItems`)

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data.
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    id response = [responseString objectFromJSONString];
    self.homepageItems = (NSArray *)response; 
    // and others have said you need to reload the tableView
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: This work, however when I scroll the table view crashes. Im guessing there is a retain issue somewhere?

Comment: 'unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12dc5e8'. Happens when I assign cell.textLabel.text

Comment: That would suggest that dataItem is not an NSDictionary. Can you post the stack trace? (when it crashes type `bt` in the debugger console. (after the `(gdb)`)

Comment: Looks like it was a problem with a character in message being returned. Ill have to investigate that separately. Thanks @Jonathan.

Answer (score 2):

Try reloading the data!

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    id response = [responseString objectFromJSONString];

    //Use self. to properly retain and you do not need to cast id assignments
    self.homepageItems = response; 

    //Make sure you reload the data!!
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to be any difference

Comment: Well now you need to make sure `homepageItems` is an array, not nil and the count is greater than 0, also make sure the elements are dictionaries and have a non empty value for the key `message`. Start setting breakpoints and logging values.

Comment: Have you updated the numberOfRowsInSection to be the size of the array?

Comment: I've set the number of rows, sorry I should have included that in the post. In the requestFinished method I've set a breakpoint and can see the data coming back. However in the cellforRow method, it doesnt look homepageItems is populated yet or at all.

Comment: @barfoon: Add a minimal example of what you logged for the `homePageItems` object.

Comment: @Joe updated the post. homepageItems is fine in the requestFinished method, yet in the tableview method, it seems to have no idea about homepageItems (yet I'm casting to a dictionary in the same way as I do in my log). Any ideas?

Comment: I needed to include self.homepageItems as well as reload the data. Thanks @Joe.

Answer (score 2):

You need to retain the homepageItems

```
 self.homepageItems = (NSArray *)response;
```

And also reload the tableview as Joe said

Answer (score 0):

You can  use this cocoapod https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLData in order to fetch data from an API endpoint and populate a UITableView/UICollectionView.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to create an php page which displays your API strings,before you can parse the elements and import they to wherever you want,its much easier!Related to your code i suppose you need to parse the element,as you can se here : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ioschat/.
Lucky.

Comment: The API call is working - the responseString is correctly appearing when it is assigned.